ubuntu server folder permission
1.i Have a SMB share mounted in /mnt/homelab
2.it auto mounts via fstab with login credentials

i can create dir in /mnt/homelab  with sudo mkdir test

I need the user karl to have access to this folder and it contents

i have tried adding karl to the sudoers via sudo usermod -aG sudo karl


i have also made a group called media added karl to it and i think gave the group permissions to the folder and still a no go.
what am i missing?

Please edit your question (don't post the output of the commands as comments) and add the output of the following commands: cat /etc/fstab, stat /mnt/homelab, getent group media. Please read here for instructions on how to properly format output of commands into the question.
